# Excel macro: Last non-empty cell in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

This is a followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5441885/69537).

The following formula can be used to find the value of the last non-empty cell in a column, in Microsoft Excel:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

My question is, how can I convert this formula to a Macro function? So that I can use it like this:

```
=GetLastValueInColumn('A')
```

Indeed, I need to convert the letter 'A' to range A:A, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Either just use the worksheet-formula in your macro as well, i.e.

```
Function GetLastValueInColumn(r As Range) As Range
  GetLastValueInColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.LOOKUP(2,1/(r<>""),r)
End Function
```

Or use some VBA specific methods, a couple are detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785291/4497791) on  StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

AS eirikdaude wrote, there are many ways to accomplish your primary task in VBA.

To accomplish the conversion of a string into a range object referring to the entire column, you can use something like:

```
Function LastValueInColumn(COL)
  Dim R as Range
  Set R = Cells(1,COL).EntireColumn
```

This will work (set R to the desired column) provided COL is a valid column letter or number.  But it will cause a run-time error if, for example, COL is a range object or an Invalid column reference.  So, depending on your application, you may need to do some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Public Function GetLastValue(rIn As Range) As Variant
    Dim N as Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, rIn.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    GetLastValue = Cells(N, rIn.Column)
End Function
```

and use it like this:

[image]

NOTE:

this is in the desired format:

```
=GetLastValue(A:A)
```